# Анимация нажатия на кнопку без дополнительного изображения

Tags: android

Данная тема, может не в данном контексте, но уже не однократно подымалась. Но прочитав кучу статей так решения и не нашел (возможно плохо искал). И так, данные:
имеется кнопка с `background`:

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
       android:background="@drawable/button_bg">
  </Button>
```

где `@drawable/button_bg` - является `selector` следующего вида:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_press" > 
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg" />
</selector>
```

где `@drawable/btn_bg_press` и `@drawable/btn_bg` - это `btn_bg.png` и `btn_bg_press.png` (тот же `btn_bg.png` только в фотошопе сделан темнее) в каталоге `drawable`, т.е. соответствующие картинки на обычное состояние кнопки и при ее нажатии.

Таким образом, вопрос в следующем:
Можно ли сделать какую-нибудь анимацию на `background`, в данном случае это затемнение основного `background` (`btn_bg.png`), т.е. получить что-то вроде следующего селектора:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg"
    android:brightness="50%"> 
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg" />
</selector>
```

т.е. использовать только одно изображение `btn_bg.png` (`@drawable/btn_bg`).

P.S.

Хотел попробовать сделать это программно, хотя вариант с xml выглядит лучше, вот что получилось:

```
StateListDrawable drawList = new StateListDrawable();
Drawable bg = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_bg);
bg.setAlpha(100);
drawList.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, bg);
button.setBackgroundDrawable(drawList);
```

т.е. достал картинку `button_bg.png`, сделал ее немного прозрачной, после чего закинул ее в `StateListDrawable` как фон по умолчанию. В итоге фон показывается, но без изменений, т.е. без прозрачности (прозрачность взял для теста, если бы все получилось, то потом уже поработал бы изменением яркости). А вот когда я применяю фон напрямую используя `bg`, прозрачность применяется (т.е. вместо `button.setBackgroundDrawable(drawList);` делаю `button.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);`). В общем, прошу вашей помощи в данном вопросе. Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Программно можно сделать примерно так. Добавить метод типа этого:

```
private Drawable createPressedImage(Drawable d) { 
  BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) d; 
  Bitmap bm = bd.getBitmap(); 
  int w = bm.getWidth(); 
  int h = bm.getHeight(); 
  Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, bm.getConfig()); 
  for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) { 
      int hexColor = bm.getPixel(i, j); 
      hexColor = ...; // ваши изменения цвета
      result.setPixel(i, j, hexColor); 
    } 
  } 
  return new BitmapDrawable(result);
}
```

И использовать его для получения `Drawable` в нажатом состоянии, передавая туда ваш `btn_bg.png`. Ну и установить его программно для вашего компонента.

Comment: конечно это дело добровольное, но помоему то что вы описали (перебор пикселей) это уровень первого курса универа а то и школы. Программно это реализуется с помощью LayerDrawable и GradientDrawable

Comment: Данный метод подходит под мою задачу, но я его немножко переписал используя статью http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-brightness-over-image/ :) В итоге все получилось. Как именно это я реализовал можно посмотреть на форуме http://androidforums.ru/Animaciya-nazhatiya-bez-dop-izobrazheniya-t10521.html (решение здесь опубликовать не могу не хватает очком :( )

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется, можно. Тогда вместо картинки с градиентом вам нужно ссылаться на другую xml-ку, которая уже в свою очередь будет ссылаться на картинку.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="1sp" android:bottom="26sp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#80000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="2sp" android:top="3sp" android:right="2sp"
        android:bottom="2sp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon"/>  
        </shape>    
    </item>    
</layer-list>
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Попробовал, как вы написали. Но у меня в итоге на нажатие показывается черный квадрат (прямоугольник), а сама картинка скрывается под этим черным квадратом.

Comment: значит чтото не совсем так сделали. Подробно см. тут http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: сделал следующим образом:
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg"/> 
   <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#80000000"
                android:endColor="#80000000"/>
        </shape>
   </item> 
</layer-list>
т.е. сверху рисую полупрозрачный прямоугольник. Все работает, но если наша исходная png имеет неровные края, то в итоге мы получаем дополнительный полупрозрачный контур что не очень хорошо смотрится.

Comment: использовал gradient т.к. при solid прямоугольник не хотел применять прозрачность

Comment: тогда нужно использовать radial gradient с параметрами в центре - самый тёмный участок, по краям полностью прозрачный

Comment: если я правильно понял это рисуется круг, т.е. это хорошо подойдет для тех случаев если фон квадратный (смотрится вполне прилично), но вот если кнопка прямоугольная с неровными краями, то данный круг в центре смотрится не очень. В этом случае лучше использовать пример выше (по крайней мере других решений именно по затемнению я пока не нашел)